# DeviceId and app permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app (S Educate) requires me to get the DeviceId (for Analytics/Recommendations) and hence I added the permission, `READ_PHONE_STATE` and although the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) is harmless, when the user installs, the app permissions window shows, "Phone Calls - Monitor, record, and process phone calls" which obviously prevents user from installing and users have informed that they are not installing simply because of this permission.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Here are my options:

1. I state clearly in my app description that I require this permission to get DeviceId and not to monitor/record phone calls and hope the users believe me and install the app
2. I find an alternate way to get DeviceId - which to my knowledge is not available without using the above mentioned permission

Please advise how do I get around this permission issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use [an app-generated UUID](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). This will allow you to distinguish one app installation from another, without violating user privacy.

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways you can retrieve Unique device id in Android.

1. IMEI (for this, You will need to add READ_PHONE_STATE Permission in Manifest)
2. Pseudo Unique ID (no need to add READ_PHONE_STATE permission)
3. Android ID
4. MAC Address

Check out the details below.
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2011/02/android-unique-device-id/#.UsMCatIW2vE

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

> In the past, when every Android device was a phone, things were simpler: TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() is required to return (depending on the network technology) the IMEI, MEID, or ESN of the phone, which is unique to that piece of hardware.

**Mac Address**

> It may be possible to retrieve a Mac address from a device’s WiFi or
>   Bluetooth hardware. We do not recommend using this as a unique
>   identifier. To start with, not all devices have WiFi. Also, if the
>   WiFi is not turned on, the hardware may not report the Mac address.

**Serial Number**

> Since Android 2.3 (“Gingerbread”) this is available via
>   android.os.Build.SERIAL. Devices without telephony are required to
>   report a unique device ID here; some phones may do so also.

**ANDROID_ID**

> More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit
>   quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It
>   is reset when the device is wiped.
>
> ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier. There
>   are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android
>   prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one
>   widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer,
>   where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

Solution is given on android blog. Use `Installation.id(context)`.

```
public class Installation {
    private static String sID = null;
    private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {  
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```