# UniquedID of Android Device (not for tracking installations)

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

So I've read numerous posts here on SO (some of which have really old answers) and posts all over Google but I still can't seem to find a definitive answer/solution for my current problem. For our mobile app we need to be able to generated a unique id that would be persistent to the device as we want to keep track of login attempts from each device. I know there's tons of caveats when dealing with various versions and OS's, so just to help with finding the best answer we are only targeting Version 16 (JellyBean) and above and for the most part our user base is only going to be using phones and tablets to use this app (it's a specific app for our clients that use our web application). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861136/deviceid-and-app-permissions/20861398#20861398